# XML refers to not existing parent

Tags: xml, data-structures, dhtmlx

In one of my application, I'm using the `dhtmlx` grid tree to show a tree structure. The
structure is getting formed in the form a xml with a parent id. Now if i send one more request (clicking some other tab in my portal) before the xml gets loaded, I'm getting one alert message saying **"DataStructure","XML refers to not existing parent"**
The xml output (to be shown in the tree structure) is like below. How can i get rid of this alert message (i don't want to change the source code of the dhtmlxtree.js file)
I'm using the below code to generate the xml in my jsp

function initTree()
{

```
var myTree = new dhtmlXTreeObject(this.divId,"100%","100%",0);  
var divId=this.divId;
myTree.setSkin('dhx_skyblue');
myTree.setImagePath("<html:imagesPath/>treeImgs/");
myTree.enableTreeLines(true);   
myTree.setXMLAutoLoading(this.loadUrl());
this.setTreeObject(myTree);
myTree.loadXML(<"some_url">);
```

}

The output xml which will generate from the above call is something look like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<tree id="0">
<item id="Device Location">
<itemtext><![CDATA[<a href="###" onClick="viewDevice(0,'Device Location','null')">Device Location</a>]]></itemtext>
</item>
<item id="Belgium">
<itemtext><![CDATA[<a href="###" onClick="viewDevice(1,'Belgium','null')">Belgium</a>]]></itemtext>
</tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

Such issue arises if your server script generates incorrect branches id in a dynamic tree.
Pleace, check your server side script.

[Look at this sample](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/samples/12_loading_processing_data/03_pro_dyn_operations.html)